# Is it possible to use air entrainment for air conditioning

Tags: heat-transfer, airflow, temperature

I have seen this video pretending to decrease by 5° the temperature inside home using an air-conditioner based on the [air entrainment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7868/why-does-the-air-we-blow-exhale-out-from-our-mouths-change-from-hot-to-cold-depe) principle (see the [video here at 1m6s](https://youtu.be/jPuh8IFbIzQ?t=1m6s)).

**EDIT : The video is now private but you can see a picture of the air-conditioner [here](http://www.iflscience.com/environment/these-diy-ecofriendly-air-conditioners-are-cooling-down-bangladesh/)**

Does such an air-conditioner really work?

Comment: The video appears to be private so I can't see it.  But this air entrainment principle seems to be you can cool a fluid down by mixing the hot fluid with a cooler one.  In which case it would certainly be possible to do this if you had a cooler fluid. However, there are plenty of cases where we want to cool a room down below ambient air temperature which would not be possible using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This device is not really working using the principles referenced in the other SE article.  In this case the air inside the hut is being heated by the sun and this is really about improving ventilation and letting that heated air out.

I think, however, it would perform worse than a fully open window from a heat transfer point of view, however, it would also act as a screen for privacy/exclusion reasons.

I also have doubts it works much better with the bottles than without them (ie. just a series of holes).  The article mentions the bottles are used to funnel cold air in but holes would allow that too. Also, the bottles would cause more interference with the drawing out of hot air if the wind is blowing parallel to the wall than simple holes would.

TL:DR It would certainly help cool the air inside, but I think simpler methods would work better.

**EDIT: Apparently this question has appeared on multiple SE see: [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/261284/how-does-the-eco-cooler-air-conditioner-really-work) and [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34302/does-the-eco-cooler-device-cool-the-air-in-a-home-without-electricity)**